# Receiving Datatype Conversion Error in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I get the following error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

For the below code:

- `a.name` is of char datatype,
- `b.type` is char,
- `c.sign` is nchar and
- `d.amount` is numeric

```
 case when a.name='abc' and b.type='X' and c.sign='+' then 1*(d.amount)
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Based on your description of the types, this line of code should not generate an error.

Comment: Can you post your entire SQL statement and what you have tried to fix this so far?

Answer (score 2):

This line is not causing your problem:

```
case when a.name = 'abc' and b.type = 'X' and c.sign = '+'
     then 1*(d.amount)
```

because all the types are being used correctly.  What is probably happening is that another path in the `case` expression returns a string, say:

```
(case when a.name = 'abc' and b.type = 'X' and c.sign = '+'
      then 1 * (d.amount)
      else 'N/A'
 end)
```

Because one path returns a number, the overall expression returns a number and you get a type conversion error.

You need to remember that a `case` expression returns a single value with a single type.  All the paths in the `case` should return the same type.  In this case, either return `NULL` or convert the number to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
case when a.name = 'abc' and b.type = 'X' and c.sign = '+'
      then 1 * (d.amount)
      else NULL
 end
```